# how to hold another api untill where current api getting refresh token flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, interceptor, dio

I'm using dio Interceptor and the user touch multiple events in a whole app and the api are triggered multiple times and every request call refresh token at the same time and return
400 issue logout to login page

I also tried `Future.wait`  but it trigerred multiple api are given at same time, it will wait return respone

but here the user touch other event where the current api aldready loading and event call api then two api getting refresh will return issue session expired

So how to hold  another api until where  current api get refresh token then allow that api get data

```
class  Interceptor{
static Dio dio({dynamic data}) {
    final dio = Dio();

dio.interceptors.add(AuthInterceptor(dio: dio));

    return dio;
  }
}
```

```
class AuthInterceptor extends QueuedInterceptor {
  final Dio? dio;
  BuildContext? context;

  AuthInterceptor({this.dio, this.context});

  @override
  void onRequest(
      RequestOptions options, RequestInterceptorHandler handler) async {
    final accessToken = await Mystorage.read('access');
    final refreshToken = await Mystorage.read('refresh');
   
    
    

    if (accessToken == null || refreshToken == null) {
      Nav.navKey.currentState!
          .pushReplacementNamed('/login');
    }
    

    
    bool accessisExpired = JwtDecoder.isExpired(accessToken ?? " ");


    if (accessisExpired ) {
    

      try {
        _refresh = await Api.refresh();
      } on DioError catch (e) {
        if (e.type == DioErrorType.sendTimeout ||
            e.type == DioErrorType.connectionTimeout ||
            e.type == DioErrorType.receiveTimeout) {
          return handler.next(options);
        } else if (e.error is SocketException) {
          print(e);
          print('f net');

          return handler.next(options);
        }
      }
      if (_refresh == true) {
        
        options.headers["Authorization"] =
            "Bearer ${await Mystorage.read("access")}";
       
        options.headers["accept"] = "application/json";
        options.connectTimeout = const Duration(seconds: 120);
        options.receiveTimeout = const Duration(seconds: 90);

        return handler.next(options);
      } else if (_refresh == null) {
       
       Nav.navKey.currentState!
            .pushReplacementNamed('/login');
      } else {
       
        bool anotherchech = JwtDecoder.isExpired(
            await Securestorage.read('access') ?? " ");
        if (anotherchech) {
          
          Nav.navKey.currentState!
              .pushReplacementNamed('/loginpage');
          
        } else {
          print('f 6');
          options.headers["Authorization"] =
              "Bearer ${await Mystorage.read("access")}";
          options.headers["x-api-key"] = Url.clientId;
          options.headers["accept"] = "application/json";

          options.connectTimeout = const Duration(seconds: 120);
          options.receiveTimeout = const Duration(seconds: 90);

          return handler.next(options);
        }
      }
    } else {
      print('4');
      options.headers["Authorization"] =
          "Bearer ${await Mystorage.read("access")}";
      options.headers["x-api-key"] = Url.clientId;
      options.headers["accept"] = "application/json";

      options.connectTimeout = const Duration(seconds: 120);
      options.receiveTimeout = const Duration(seconds: 90);

      return handler.next(options);
    }
  }

 

  @override
  void onError(DioError err, ErrorInterceptorHandler handler) async {
    }
}
```

```
class Repo{
Future callapi(){
var response = await Interceptor.dio(data: typeId).post(
      "${Api.url}/xxxxxx",
      data: l,
    );
   

    return response;
}
}
```